# Nuke build .nuke file and build multiple solutions

Tags: c#, build, msbuild, nuke-build

I am using [nuke build](https://nuke.build/) for the first time.

Working through the [getting started](https://nuke.build/docs/getting-started/setup.html) guide, I have ran the following:

```
dotnet tool install Nuke.GlobalTool --global
nuke :setup
```

This ran through a wizard which generated:

1. build folder containing a csharp project to do the build
2. .nuke file
3. build.ps1 and build.sh to run the build

The .nuke file seems to contain a solution I selected during the build.  Now I have a few solutions located under a folder that I want to build.

So I was assuming I could put them in the `.nuke` file.

```
code/solution1/solution1.sln
code/solution2/solution2.sln
code/solution3/solution3.sln
```

To no avail.  When I run the build.ps1, it only builds the first solution in the list.

And the only help I see about the .nuke file states "Root directory marker file; references default solution file"

Question is, using the nuke build, how can I build multiple solutions under a folder hierarchy?

Comment: There's a slack workspace for nuke at https://slofile.com/slack/nukebuildnet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe it's designed for this - instead you need to have one nuke build per solution.

Answer (score 3):

The `.nuke` file is currently mainly used for the `SolutionAttribute`. Eventually, it will be replaced by using `global.json`. If you're building multiple solutions, I suggest creating an `IEnumerable<Solution>` property and using [combinatorial invocations](http://www.nuke.build/docs/authoring-builds/cli-tools.html) via MSBuild or dotnet CLI.

Answer (score 2):

This is also my usecase and I'll eagerly await the global.json file :) Since I was also wondering about multiple solution targets/etc, this is roughly what I have gathered:

The .nuke file is there for finding the injected RootDirectory (which is used by other internals afaik), and also can contain the default solution if you use the [Solution] attribute with no parameters.
You can set up the  combinatorial invocations as talked about by Matthias by either:

1. Setting up injected static solution files:

```cs
//inside of build.cs
[Solution("Test1/example1.csproj")]
readonly Solution ExampleSolution1;

[Solution("Test2/example2.csproj")]
readonly Solution ExampleSolution2;
```

2. Creating Solution objects at runtime

```cs
//anywhere in any task or function -- if moved, just pass in RootDirectory
IEnumerable<Solution> solutions = new[]{
     ProjectModelTasks.ParseSolution(RootDirectory / "Test1/example1.csproj"),
     ProjectModelTasks.ParseSolution(RootDirectory / "Test2/example2.csproj"),
 };
```